# How to define polymorphic tagless final lists

Tags: haskell, tagless-final

After reading the excellent and interesting paper
[Typed Tagless-Final Interpretations: Introductory Course](https://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/index.html)
from Oleg Kiselyov I tried to convert normal Haskell lists to Tagless Final lists and failed:

This is working:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module TList

where

class TList repr  where
  tnil :: repr
  tcons :: Int -> repr -> repr

tlist0 :: TList repr => repr
tlist0 = tnil

tlist1 :: TList repr => repr
tlist1 = tcons 1 $ tcons 2 $ tcons 3 tnil

instance TList String where
  tnil = "tnil"
  tcons hd tail = "tcons " ++ show hd ++ " $ " ++ tail

view :: String -> String
view = id
```

Executing `view tlist1` in GHCi gives `tcons 1 $ tcons 2 $ tcons 3 $ tnil`

With the definition above the type of the elements of the list is restricted to `Int`! I would like to have polymorphic lists and tried:

```
class PList repr a where
  pnil :: repr a
  pcons :: a -> repr a -> repr a

plist0 :: forall (repr :: * -> *) a. PList repr a => repr a
plist0 = pnil

plist1 :: PList repr Int => repr Int
plist1 = pcons 1 $ pcons 2 $ pcons 3 pnil
```

This compiles, but I'm unable to define the instance for the interpreter:

```
instance PList String where
  pnil = "pnil"
  pcons hd tail = "pcons " ++ show hd ++ " $ " ++ tail
```

This gives the error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling TList            ( List/List.hs, interpreted ) [Source file changed]

List/List.hs:30:10: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘PList String’
      Expected a constraint,
        but ‘PList String’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘PList String’
   |
30 | instance PList String where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

List/List.hs:30:16: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘PList’, namely ‘String’
      In the instance declaration for ‘PList String’
   |
30 | instance PList String where
   |                ^^^^^^
```

So `PList` should have 2 type arguments! Changing to `instance PList String Int where` gives:

```
List/List.hs:30:16: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘PList’, namely ‘String’
      In the instance declaration for ‘PList String Int’
   |
30 | instance PList String Int where
   |                ^^^^^^
```

So I should have a type with kind `(* -> *)` like Functor or so, but I don't have it. How to fix?

Comment: Should it be `pcons :: a -> repr a -> repr a` ? element plus list makes list?

Comment: @user253751 Aarrgh!! Of course you are right. Many thanks for your hint! Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem. I'll edit my question.

Comment: In meantime I have edited my question.

Comment: In your new approach `repr` should be something allowing one to make lists of any type: `repr Int`, `repr Bool`, `repr String` must be list-like types. You can no longer define a `repr` for only one case as in the previous approach. You can't choose `repr = String` since `String Int` is a kind error. You likely need to define your own `data MyList a = ...` and then choose `repr = MyList` when you define the instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Many thanks for your answer. Down the road I'd like to be able to define some of the list functions eg `head`. For this I'll need the type of the contained elements. I'll work with both of your suggestions during the next days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you want to retain the type information of the "contained" element in the representation. You could certainly keep it, through a phantom argument

```
newtype TypyString a = TypyString { stringyString :: String }
```

which has a suitable kind for the current class.

But I think it's more in the spirit of the original to *not* carry that information around. Then it doesn't make sense for `repr a` to appear in the signatures. It doesn't need to, you can just have a plain `repr` there. GHC may balk at you for having ambiguous types, but that's not a problem any longer with the right extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class PList repr a where
  pnil :: repr
  pcons :: a -> repr -> repr
```

and then you can define

```
instance PList String Int where
  pnil = "pnil"
  pcons hd tail = "pcons " ++ show hd ++ " $ " ++ tail
```

...or more generally,

```
instance Show a => PList String a where
  ...
```

The examples will however need to take care of the ambiguity:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, UnicodeSyntax #-}

plist0 :: ∀ repr a . PList repr a => repr
plist0 = pnil @repr @a

plist1 :: ∀ repr . PList repr Int => repr
plist1 = pcons @repr @Int 1
       . pcons @repr @Int 2
       . pcons @repr @Int 3
       $ pnil @repr @Int
```

This is quite awkward, and also unnecessary because the `repr` argument isn't actually ambiguous, rather the `a` one is. It's nicer when the type arguments are swapped:

```
class PList a repr where
  pnil :: repr
  pcons :: a -> repr -> repr

instance PList Int String where
  ...

plist0 :: ∀ a . PList a => repr
plist0 = pnil @a

plist1 :: PList repr Int => repr
plist1 = pcons @Int 1 . pcons @Int 2 . pcons @Int 3 $ pnil @Int
```

You wouldn't even need the `@Int` applications for the `pcons`es if the number-literals where unambiguous, which they aren't in Haskell but could be made to be:

```
plist1 :: PList Int repr => repr
plist1 = pcons n1 . pcons n2 . pcons n3 $ pnil @Int
 where n1,n2,n3 :: Int
       (n1,n2,n3) = (1,2,3)
```